# Cron runs .sh file without any result

Tags: linux, cron

I just made a little .sh script which just downloads a .txt file from the web. I want this to be run every two minutes.

getfeed.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILENAME=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M"`.txt
cd feedhistory
/usr/bin/wget -O $FILENAME http://www.example.com/link/to/file.txt
```

Crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/src/cron/getfeed.sh
```

Syslog entry:

```
Sep 24 XX:XX:XX servername CRON[10451]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /var/www/src/cron/getfeed.sh)
```

The .sh file itself works fine and the syslog shows Cron is doing something with the file. But there is nothing downloaded...

Thanks in advance

Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually cron runs the command in the user's home directory. Your cron job doesn't specify a user, so it will be executed by root.

As your `$FILENAME` does not contain a path, the file should be downloaded to the `/root/` directory of your system.

If you want them to be somewhere else, you should either set a user for the cron job, or set an absolute path for the download destination.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, lxg! I will try that later :)